# How can I compute the rolling average of a column up to a certain number of rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

| HorseId | FGrating |
| --- | --- |
| 25620 | 112 |
| 25620 | 108 |
| 25620 | 111 |
| 25620 | 98 |
| 25620 | 103 |
| 25620 | 96 |

I want to compute the rolling average of the `FGrating` column according to these rules:

1. If I have 4 or more races of a certain `HorseId`, then I compute the rolling average for the last 4 races;
2. If I have less than 4 races, then I compute the rolling average for the races that I have so far.

The average should be displayed on the following row of the rows used to compute the aforementioned metric. As an example: the rolling average for the first 4 races should be displayed on the 5th row. So, on the first row the correct value is 0

What I am looking for is a table like this:

| HorseId | FGrating | Rolling average |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25620 | 112 | 0 |
| 25620 | 108 | 112 (112/1) |
| 25620 | 111 | 110 (112+108)/2 |
| 25620 | 98 | 110.33 (112+108+111)/3 |
| 25620 | 103 | 107.25 (112+108+111+98)/4 |
| 25620 | 96 | 105 (108+111+98+103)/4 |

So far, I got to the rolling average of the last 4 races, like this:

```
df.groupby('HorseId')['FGrating'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().expanding(min_periods=no_starts).mean())
```

But I am stuck with the rest. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try to use [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#new-syntax-to-window-and-resample-operations) and [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) :

```
df['Rolling_Average'] = df.groupby('HorseID')['FGrating']/
    .shift(1).transform(lambda x: x.rolling(4, 1).mean())
```

rolling creates a window, which could be use to calculate moving average, and shift shifts the row (so it wouldn't take actual row)

```
    HorseID FGrating    Rolling_Average
0   25620   112         NaN
1   25620   108         112.000
2   25620   111         110.000
3   25620   98          110.333
4   25620   103         107.250
5   25620   96          105.000
```

Comment: Brilliant answer +1.

Comment: I had to put the ```shift``` into the lambda function from the ```transform``` , or otherwise the results weren't taking into account the grouping phase. Otherwise, your answer is spot on.

Answer (score 1):

Use `rolling_mean`:

```
df['Rolling_Average'] = df.groupby('HorseId')['FGrating'].rolling(4, min_periods=1) \
                          .mean().shift(fill_value=0).droplevel(0)
print(df)

# Output:
   HorseId  FGrating            Rolling average  Rolling_Average
0    25620       112                          0              NaN
1    25620       108                112 (112/1)       112.000000
2    25620       111            110 (112+108)/2       110.000000
3    25620        98     110.33 (112+108+111)/3       110.333333
4    25620       103  107.25 (112+108+111+98)/4       107.250000
5    25620        96     105 (108+111+98+103)/4       105.000000
```

Comment: Great answer. I gave you an upvote, but I cannot accept two answers for the same question. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @BogdanDoicin. Why use a `lambda` function to compute the `mean`?

Comment: What is the difference between using and not using ```lambda```?